# Is there any way to get merge fields ordered from word in python? I am using get_merge_fields()

Tags: python

My program gets all the merge fields from docx, look for some specific words and replace them.

But I need the merge fields to be in the same order as inserted in document.

If I have this content in word:

> << Market.Name >> has << Market.Employees >> and closes at << Market.ClosingHour >>, while << Hotel.Name >> has << Hotel.Employees >> and closes at << Hotel.ClosingHour >>. << PetShop.Name >> owner is << PetShop.Owner >> .

when I use get_merge_fields() from doc, it gives me all the fields, but I want them in the following order:

> {'Market.Name', 'Market.Employees', 'Market.ClosingHour', 'Hotel.Name', 'Hotel.Employees', 'Hotel.ClosingHour', 'PetShop.Name', 'PetShop.Owner'}

I need this to create forms that have the same order for Name, Employees, ClosingHour and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. get_merge_fields() method returns a set which is an unordered data structure, so I changed get_merge_fields() method like this:

```
def get_merge_fields(self, parts=None):
    if not parts:
        parts = self.parts.values()
    fields = []
    for part in parts:
        for mf in part.findall('.//MergeField'):
            fields.append(mf.attrib['name'])
    return fields
```